# Example of two-level systems which has very long lifetime "in nature" but as soon as we manipulate them their lifetime is very small

Tags: experimental-realization

I am looking for examples of quantum systems which could serve as qubits (electron spin, electrical levels of ions, whatever) that verify the following properties:

1. In nature they can have very long coherence time (they can maintain information for a "long" amount of time)
2. As soon as one tries to use them as qubits (hence to manipulate them), their lifetime becomes much smaller

I am pretty sure there are plenty of examples like that, but I would like some concrete references for concrete physical systems. It is to illustrate the point that as soon as we try to manipulate quantum systems we almost unavoidably make them much noisier than what they are without being manipulated.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-20330-w Is this something that you are finding for?

Comment: @Yunzhe Hello. In this paper they exhibit a long coherence time for a memory but they do not compare it to the quality if the ion was manipulated. I guess I could cross-check that with other papers about ions. Yet ideally I would like one ref that explicitly say that if the qubit is not manipulated it can have very good quality, but when we manipulate it with, say, single qubit gates; its fidelity is much worse. Or that it compares the quality of the qubit in the experimental setup vs its quality "in nature" (for instance an electron spin).

Comment: I think it's a little tricky to successfully identify a system that is both a good quantum memory and a bad computing platform. You need to find a system where the control infidelity is very high, and this is true for most state-of-the-art hardware. Maybe I missed some of your idea but It's quite easy to destroy the coherence with quantum operations and most people are trying to not destroy the coherence too much. Also, the "quality in nature" is not a well-defined term in my opinion as magnetic field exists in our world and it could easily destroy quantum decoherence.

Comment: it's better to clarify the description in your question, e.g. : How long is enough to be called "long coherence"? People working with quantum dots might feel millisecond is already long enough but for other platforms, e.g. neutral atoms, coherence time can be easily over seconds.

Comment: @Yunzhe To give you an example of something I am looking for. I am pretty sure I have read somewhere that electron's spin can have crazy lifetime inside of natural material. But as soon as we try to use it as a computing platform (so isolate it inside a well engineered environment), the lifetime is much much worse than what it is in nature. Some resources showing this would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

A notable *counter* example to this idea is dynamical decoupling / spin echo. Qubits often have longer lifetimes when you're constantly flipping them, instead of letting them sit still, because the flipping causes any slow drift to cancel itself out instead of accumulating.